# Rundeck has suddenly become painfully slow

Tags: rundeck

We have been running Rundeck opensource v3.4.10 in our K8s cluster for months with really no problems.  Suddenly yesterday something changed that we can't explain.  Rundeck has become painfully slow taking a minute or two for each page to load.  Sometimes it will just timeout on the ingress proxy.

I have tried restarting every pod involved.  I have also tried restating the RDS database.  Finally I tried upgrading to version 4.2 but that made things worse so we went back to our older version.

Anyone else experience something similar?  Any idea where to start?  I haven't found any errors so far.

Comment: Hi! Do you see any clue in the container log?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the rundeck logs.  I do see timeouts happening in the ingress controller logs.  But Linkerd says the response between the two is fast.

Comment: Could you check this solution? https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6411#issuecomment-701330906